# jQuery - use canvas to draw lines between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, canvas

I have n `<div`>s, each with `<h1`> title and `<ul`> list of items in.

I would like to float these over a canvas and draw lines from `<div id="x"`> list item y to `<div id="z"`>. I am using jQuery UI to make the `<div`>s draggable.

The canvas element is part way down the page (a paragraph of text and some form elements precede it) but I can change this if necessary.

[edit]

I tagged the question with graph, but let me add this link: [Graph_(mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) :-)

Answer (score 7):

I would make the div's positioning to absolute and then set them where you want. Then get their position with this function:

```
//Get the absolute position of a DOM object on a page
function findPos(obj) {
    var curLeft = curTop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curLeft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curTop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }
    return {x:curLeft, y:curTop};
}
```

When you have their position, add it to half their width/height, and you will have the position of their center on the page. Now find the position of the canvas and substract it from the previously found numbers. If you draw a line between those two points, it should link the two divs. In case it's not clear, here's how I would code it:

```
var centerX = findPos(document.getElementById('x'));
centerX.x += document.getElementById('x').style.width;
centerX.y += document.getElementById('x').style.height;
var centerZ = findPos(document.getElementById('Z'));
centerZ.x += document.getElementById('z').style.width;
centerZ.y += document.getElementById('z').style.height;
//Now you've got both centers in reference to the page
var canvasPos = findPos(document.getElementById('canvas'));
centerX.x -= canvasPos.x;
centerX.y -= canvasPos.y;
centerZ.x -= canvasPos.x;
centerZ.y -= canvasPos.y;
//Now both points are in reference to the canvas
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(centerX.x, centerX.y);
ctx.lineTo(centerZ.x, centerZ.y);
ctx.stroke();
//Now you should have a line between both divs. You should call this code each time the position changes
```

**EDIT**
By the way, using the findPos function you can also set the initial position of the divs relatively to the canvas (here at (30; 40)):

```
var position = {x: 30, y: 40};
var canvasPos = findPos(document.getElementById('canvas'));
var xPos = canvasPos.x + position.x;
var yPos = canvasPos.y + position.y;
document.getElementById('x').style.left = xPos+"px";
document.getElementById('x').style.top = yPos+"px";
```