# Draw lines on HTML page from one div to another

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to draw lines on a webpage from one div to another.  I've looked around, but all I've seen are hacks that rotate webkit images like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/MKkxX/).  Raphel.js is another possiblity, but I'd prefer to avoid importing an entire library if I can.  I also need to make sure it works in all browsers.

Is this possible, or am I off my rocker?

UPDATE: I tried Raphael, no dice.  Creating the object overwrites what I currently have.  Code (In case I did something wrong):

```
window.onload = function() {
        var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('image'), 1024, 768);/*
        var line = paper.path("M 250 250 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 50 l -50 0 l 0 50 z");
    };
```

Comment: Do they need to be straight lines are can they be vertical and horizontal connected by right angles

Comment: Check out this implementation with jQuery at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104295/jquery-use-canvas-to-draw-lines-between-divs

Comment: That uses Canvas, which doesn't work in IE.

Comment: IE == :-(, OK let's see, there is a demo that works here: http://jsbin.com/evoloy/2/edit#preview.  it doesn't use canvas

Comment: No framework AND working on all browsers is a pretty tall order.

Comment: If I have to do it with a framework, I will.  Working on all browsers is more important.

Comment: Yes I believe jQuery should be able to do it, i will give it a try this weekend.

Comment: found this one on another post: http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html

Comment: Yup, that's the one I ended up going with.  I've only done a minor amount of testing with it, so I'm not ready to make the adjustment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I could not find a way to do this without a framework, I did find a cross-browser solution in [jsPlumb](http://jsplumb.org).  (Thanks to jeffery_the_wind)