# Draw lines to connect divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have this set up: http://sandbox.brightboxstudios.com/orgmap/

They are draggable and I am trying to find a way to have lines connect them, even when they are dragged. Having an easy way to show how each is related and which should be connected is ideal!

Thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing a line between two draggable divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278152/drawing-a-line-between-two-draggable-divs)

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using the [D3.js library](http://d3js.org/). In particular this example is what I think you are looking for: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html

Comment: This seems way beyond what I'm looking for :/ Not even really sure how to integrate it.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: [jQuery - use canvas to draw lines between divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104295/jquery-use-canvas-to-draw-lines-between-divs?rq=1)

I'd start with that code, and just re-draw the lines every time the `div`s change location.

Comment: well, I just looked and it seems like the redraw works by calling `redrawCanvas()` in javascript

Comment: Sorry, how do I implement that command? Still learning :) Thanks!!

Comment: You probably want to read [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) on events. It should explain how to run javascript code when something happens in the browser. I'm not sure exactly what event you want to use though...

Comment: I found the drag event under jQuery draggable, though don't know how to incorporate it into the code you linked in your answer..

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#event-drag

Comment: try `$( "canvas" ).bind( "drag", function(event, ui) {
  redrawCanvas();
});` Don't forget to include the jQuery library, and if you have more than one canvas on the page, change the `"canvas"` to something more specific, i.e.: `"canvas#linecanvas"`, that will match all canvases with an ID of "linecanvas"

Answer (score 1):

You may try KineticJS too. I think that it will provide what you want easily. http://www.kineticjs.com/

Here you can find lots of tutorials: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-events-tutorials-introduction-with-kineticjs/

Comment: I saw that, though could not figure out the lines connecting still.. any ideas?

Comment: Do you think is it good idea to use not anymore maintained libraries? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/jquery/demo.html), a JavaScript library that can connects divs together. It's really simple to use and there are plenty of demos on that page.